# VBA macro to interchange columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Please could you help me in VBA macro to interchange columns

for example There are 4 columns

Supplier1, Supplier2, Supplier Score1, Supplier Score2

I want to change columns as below

Supplier1, Supplier Score1, Supplier2, Supplier Score2

I have used the below code

Columns("I:I").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

Comment: I have used the below code

Comment: Columns("I:I").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

Comment: You should [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/961050/edit) your question to add details of your code. It seems like an example of your table might help too. What is failing with your code exactly?

Comment: I want to use this for n number of columns, eg, there are n number of columns Supplier1, Supplier2..... Suppliern, Supplier Score1, Supplier Score2..... Supplier Score n and I want to interchange to Supplier1, Supplier Score1, Supplier2, Supplier Score2..... Supplier n, Supplier Score n

Answer (score 0):

You might find the code I posted in my mini-blog here to be of some interest...

http://www.excelfox.com/forum/f22/swapping-rearranging-multiple-columns-of-data-493/

Comment: Please edit your answer so there is more than just a link. [`Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.`](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

Your specifications are not entirely clear.  But it seems you want to interleave the first half of your columns with the second half.  This can be done fairly simply and quickly in VBA.  I have made assumptions, which you will need to edit, as to where the Original data is located, and where you want to place the Results.  I have also assumed that the data is contiguous, as noted in the code comments.

This is accomplished in VBA arrays, as routines which repeatedly access the worksheet are much slower.

The algorithm used:

- Read the data into a 2D variant array
- create a second array to hold the results, same size as the first
- populate the second array by interleaving the first and second half column ranges.
- write the results array to a worksheet range.
- format the results

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub InterleaveColumns()
    Dim wsORIG As Worksheet, wsRESULT As Worksheet, rRESULT As Range
    Dim lNumCols As Long
    Dim vORIG As Variant, vRESULT() As Variant
    Dim I  As Long, J As Long

'Place Results starting on Sheet3!A1
Set wsRESULT = Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set rRESULT = wsRESULT.Cells(1, 1)

'Assuming the data table starts Sheet2!A1 and is contiguous
'Adjust algorithm as required
Set wsORIG = Worksheets("Sheet2")

'Place data into a 2D Variant Array
vORIG = wsORIG.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

'Number of columns
lNumCols = UBound(vORIG, 2)

'Sanity check
If lNumCols Mod 2 <> 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Must have Even number of columns")
    Exit Sub
End If

'Create results array
ReDim vRESULT(1 To UBound(vORIG, 1), 1 To UBound(vORIG, 2))

'Populate results array with interleaving
For I = 1 To UBound(vORIG, 1)
    For J = 1 To UBound(vORIG, 2) / 2
        vRESULT(I, (J - 1) * 2 + 1) = vORIG(I, J)
        vRESULT(I, (J - 1) * 2 + 2) = vORIG(I, J + lNumCols / 2)
    Next J
Next I

'Write results array to some worksheet and range
Set rRESULT = rRESULT.Resize(UBound(vRESULT, 1), UBound(vRESULT, 2))
With rRESULT
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRESULT
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

---